# Is it possible to use ignore_watch parameter by extension or wildcard in PM2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm using pm2 for my node application. But whenever I travel between folders, or if I click to "stage changes" in VSCode, PM2 restarts the application.
I believe osX creating files like .DS_Store etc. and that triggers pm2 watch.
So I can add a wildcard to ignore that kind of file for every folder.

This is how my process.json looks like;

```
{
    "apps": [{
            "name": "server",
            "script":"index.js",
            "max_memory_restart": "1024M",
            "node_args":"--max_old_space_size=2048",
            "watch":true,
            "ignore_watch":["ext/server/reports", "node_modules", ".git", ".vscode"],
            "args":"dev",
            "env_local": {
                "NODE_ENV": "local"
            },
            ...
        }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Put a file named as `ecosystem.config.js` on the root of project.

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'project_name',
    script: 'index.js',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    restart_delay: 5000,
    watch: true,
    max_memory_restart: '512M',
    ignore_watch: ['log-*.txt'],
    error_file: 'log-error.txt',
    out_file: 'log-output.txt'
  }]
};
```

Here the parameter as `ignore-watch` will help you. e.g. In my case, I am ignoring the files as log-output.txt, log-error.txt.

Comment: Is this going to ignore the same file in every folder or just the root folder only?

Comment: this specific is for the root only

Comment: Then In my case, it doesn't cover my problem. Anywhere in the project folder, it should ignore every occurrence.

Comment: So in that case, You have to provide the path

Comment: My question is the wildcard for folders, like */.DS_Store (.DS_Store file in each directory.)